# Selenium Chrome + Python => listbox how to select a value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am trying to control page by Selenium. I have a problem with listbox.
This is how it looks:

```
<span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ddlRetentionCategory_listbox" aria-live="polite" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" style="" aria-activedescendant="3d9fac25-2597-4668-82d0-c00a04131818"><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">--Select--</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input id="ddlRetentionCategory" name="ddlRetentionCategory" type="text" value="" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"></span>
```

and this is what I need to select from dropdown/listbox:

```
<span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ddlRetentionCategory_listbox" aria-live="polite" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" style="" aria-activedescendant="3d9fac25-2597-4668-82d0-c00a04131818"><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-focused"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">2 years</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span><input id="ddlRetentionCategory" name="ddlRetentionCategory" type="text" value="" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"></span>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok I am able to open list select = driver.find_element_by_class_name('k-input').click() but I can not select 2 years

Comment: How about without clicking? `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ddlRetentionCategory').value=\"2 years\"")`

Comment: you have the website link?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"k-input"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contain(text(),'2 years')]"))).click()
```

**Try using wait, and if second line doesn't work use below code click the parent span tag instead**

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contain(text(),'2 years')]/..")))
```

**You can also use action class:**

```
option = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contain(text(),'2 years')]")))

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option ).click().perform()
```